# Portable indoor heater for emergency

Tags: heater

I am looking to buy a gas based indoor heater that I can use in emergency. I have an existing gas log fireplace but it is not modern and I am worried that in an emergency it will lead to a loss of heat overall (since the warm air when it goes up will pull air from inside the house).

Has anyone come across any safe to use indoor heating solution? I have seen propane heaters but they are only recommended to use in indoor construction environments.

Comment: I wouldn't use any unvented combustible heating device inside the home. They have been known to be [fatal](https://www.masslive.com/news/index.ssf/2011/11/unvented_space_heaters_to_blam.html), even propane heaters. Vent-free gas logs are available, but even they can be unsafe and I wouldn't trust them as a primary heating source (even emergency heat). A perfectly adjusted device might be safe, the Carbon Monoxide is a silent killer, and I wouldn't risk it, even with a CO detector.

Comment: so there is nothing i can do except a functioning fireplace ?

Comment: One option is to install a standby generator so if the power goes off, so you can still run the furnace. A newer, more efficient gas log insert can also help. I have a direct vent insert and it gives off a decent amount of heat -- enough to keep the living room warm (which is a drawback since the thermostat is in the livingroom so when the gas logs are on the rest of the house gets cold since the furnace never kicks on)

Comment: Of course, you could decide that the benefit of an unvented combustion appliance outweighs the risks -- I live in a relatively mild climate where even winter temperatures rarely dip below the mid 20's or so, so a midweight sleeping bag provides enough warmth. But if you live in an area with more extreme temperatures, you may want the security that an emergency heater can provide.

Comment: We actually don’t do product recommendations on this site.  I’m going to disagree with Johnny tho, there is such an animal as a direct vent gas fireplace.  [Here is a link to one example.](http://www.vermontcastings.com/Products/Radiance-Direct-Vent-Gas-Stove.aspx)  I have two and they work great and have provided all the heat in a power outage.   Find a local fireplace store or dealer, they can help you find “direct vent” solutions that suit your needs.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading the insulation and air sealing in your house?  That'd help significantly with reducing the heating load your house poses...

Comment: @Tyson - [direct vent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_vent_fireplace) fireplaces are fine, they bring in outside air for combustion and vent combustion products outside -- my problem is with unvented products where combustion gases are released into the home -- you have to have a lot of faith that the system is adjusted perfectly if you're going to use it to heat your home.

Comment: @Johnny please look at the link I provided above. It’s labeled direct vent however there is no outdoor combustion air, nor is there a flue.  It’s a free standing natural gas stove. I didn’t think I’d like them, we bought the house for other reasons, but I’m personally quite impressed with these units.

Comment: @Johnny besides 100% energy efficiency, the by product of natural gas ignition is water, they add quite a bit of humidity to the dry winter air as well.

Comment: That manufacturer sells both "direct vent" and "unvented" appliances -- look at the instruction manual for the "direct vent" appliances and you'll see the venting requirements. Unvented appliances *can* be safe as long as they are working properly - the byproduct of a perfectly adjusted natural gas burner is CO2 and water but if it's not perfectly adjusted, the byproducts include CO- carbon monoxide.  Since they vent combustion products directly into your home,you're relying on it to always be adjusted perfectly, if a gas log shifts and disrupts the flame, you may be filling your home with CO.

Answer (score 1):

You could install a direct vent, wall mounted, sealed combustion, heater that requires no electricity and can be fired with your existing natural gas service or a separate propane source fuel. They are readily available through a myriad of supply houses like Home Depot, Lowes, Graingers, E'bay, Amazon and local contractors. They come in almost any size you would want. For more information just use your computer search engine. This of course would not be portable but would give you heat in an emergency and would not need any electricity unless you added an optional blower fan.